# Abstract classes with operator overloading

Tags: c#

I'm following a YouTube video and am wondering if there are any other efficient ways of doing this. Is it possible to do it with an interface too?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Learning
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Shape Rect = new Rectangle(5, 3);
            Shape Tri = new Triangle(8, 12);
            Rectangle CombinedRectangle = new Rectangle(3, 3) + new Rectangle(6, 6);
            Console.WriteLine(CombinedRectangle.Area());
        }



        abstract class Shape
        {
             public abstract double Area();

        }

        class Triangle : Shape
        {
            private double theBase { get; set; }
            private double theHeight { get; set; }

            public Triangle(double theBase, double theHeight)
            {
                this.theBase = theBase;
                this.theHeight = theHeight;
            }

            public override double Area()
            {
                return (theBase * theHeight) / 2;
            }
        }

        class Rectangle : Shape
        {
            private double Length { get; set; }
            private double Width { get; set; }

            public Rectangle(double Length, double Width)
            {
                this.Length = Length;
                this.Width = Width;
            }

            public override double Area()
            {
                return Length * Width;
            }

            public static Rectangle operator+ (Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
            {
                double combinedWidth = r1.Width + r2.Width;
                double combinedLength = r1.Length + r2.Length;
                return new Rectangle(combinedLength, combinedWidth);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit leery about that use of the `+` operator. Most people wouldn't think that a 1x1 rectangle "plus" a 2x2 rectangle makes a 3x3 rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your direct question, yes an interface would be better than an abstract class.  Plus you may want to consider that `Area` could be a property rather than a method.

To address things you didn't ask about:

For the `Triangle` class, you may want to give simpler names to the base and height.  So `Base` instead of `theBase` and `Height` instead of `theHeight`.  And they should be public properties, perhaps with private setters.

```
public double Base { get; private set; }
public double Height { get; private set; }
```

For `Rectangle` class, the `Length` and `Width` could also be public.

```
public double Length { get; private set; }
public double Width { get; private set; }
```

Also the constructor should use lower casing for the arguments:

```
public Rectangle(double length, double width)
```

The operator could be shortened:

```
public static Rectangle operator+ (Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
    return new Rectangle(r1.Length + r2.Length, r2.Width+ r2.Width);
}
```

Or if you are using C# 6.0:

```
public static Rectangle operator+ (Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2) => new Rectangle(r1.Length + r2.Length, r2.Width+ r2.Width);
```

The last line uses an **Expression-bodied function member** found in C# 6.0.  A single line method body can be replaced with a 'lambda arrow' and you can omit the return since its implied.

**Putting it altogether**

Using C# version 6.0 syntax

```
interface IShape
{
    double Area { get; }
}

public class Triangle: IShape
{
    public double Base { get; private set; }
    public double Height { get; private set; }
    public Triangle(double theBase, double theHeight)
    {
        Base = theBase;
        Height = theHeight;
    }
    public double Area => (Base * Height) / 2;
}

public class Rectangle : IShape
{
    public double Length { get; private set; }
    public double Width { get; private set; }
    public Rectangle(double length, double width)
    {
        Length = length;
        Width = width;
    }
    public double Area => Length * Width;

    public static Rectangle operator+(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2) => new Rectangle(r1.Length + r2.Length, r2.Width+ r2.Width);
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what your last line (operator overloading with =>) does with the => please?

Comment: Look half way down the page for **Expression-bodied function members** in this MSDN link:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx

Comment: On the interface section where it states 'double Area { get; }', why wouldn't it be 'double Area();'? Just so I can note this down.

Comment: The signature in my example declares `Area` as a property rather than a method.  Just like `Base` and `Height` are properties of a `Triangle`, and `Length` and `Width` are properties of a `Rectangle`, it makes more sense to me that any shape would have a property of `Area`.